# Discrete Math reccurrence realtion

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that there are $n = 2^k$ teams in an elimination tournament, where there are n/2 games in the first round, with the $n/2 = 2^{k-1}$ winners playing in the second round, and so on. Develop a recurrence relation for the number of rounds in the tournament.

Would $f(n) = f(n/2) + 1$ for $n=2^k$ be a recurrence relation for the question above? would I also have to say $f(1) = 1?$

Comment: If there is one player, how many rounds does the tournament have? Hint: it's not $1$ :P

Answer (score 0):

For all recurrence relations, you will have to define the first term.

I'm not so sure about your notation with $f(n)$... perhaps you mean $T_n$ where $n$ represents the $n$th power of 2 of the number of teams and $T_n$ is the number of rounds?

In which case, I think yes.

So your recurrence relation would be:

$T_{1}$ = 0

$T_{n+1}$ = $T_n + 1$

where:

$T_n$ is the number of rounds in the tournament

$2^n$ is the number of teams in the tournament.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I got a different answer so I thought I'd share it here for anyone in the future:

Each "level" of the tournament bracket has $n=2^k$ teams. That means, for each level of the bracket, $\frac{n}{2}$ games are played (every two teams plays one game). So, the number of games played at a tournament is equal to the number of games played at the highest level ($\frac{n}{2}$), where there are $n$ teams), plus the number of games played at a tournament one level smaller.

Hence:

$T_1 = 0$

$T_n = T_{n-1} + \frac{n}{2}$

Where $T_n$ is the number of games played in a tournament with $n=2^k$ teams.